# Express.js and Node.js : Unable to set value in the request object

Tags: node.js, express

I am following Practical Node.js book. It is based on older version on express.js. The book is trying to build a blog. It has several different routes files. Ex- index.js, admin.js, article.js etc. This route classes are called from app.js. Ex:

```
app.use('/', routes.index);//// THE ISSUE IS HERE /////
app.get('/login', routes.user.login);
app.post('/login', routes.user.authenticate);
app.get('/logout', routes.user.logout);
app.get('/admin',  routes.article.admin);
app.get('/post',  routes.article.post);
app.post('/post', routes.article.postArticle);
```

Whenever someone tries to access '/', I am setting a collections object of artices and users in the request object.

```
var dbarticles = require('./db/articles.json');
var dbusers = require('./db/users.json');
app.use(function(req, res,next) {
  if (!collections.articles || ! collections.users) return next(new Error("No collections."))
  req.collections = collections;
  return next();
});

 app.use('/', routes.index);//// THE ISSUE IS HERE /////
```

The problem is that in index.js file, the value of req.collections is no available, I get 'undefined'. What am I missing. I have checked in the console.log, that the value is present in req.collections before the '/', route.index is hit.

Here's my app.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var  methodOverride = require('method-override');
var routes = require('./routes');
var dbarticles = require('./db/articles.json');
var dbusers = require('./db/users.json');
 var collections = {
    articles: dbarticles,
    users: dbusers
  };
var logger = require('morgan');
 var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
 var app = express();  

app.locals.appTitle = 'blog-express';

//console.log(collections.articles || collections.users);



app.use(function(req, res,next) {
  if (!collections.articles || ! collections.users) return next(new Error("No collections."))
  req.collections = collections;
  return next();
});



// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Pages and routes
app.use('/', routes.index);

app.get('/login', routes.user.login);
app.post('/login', routes.user.authenticate);
app.get('/logout', routes.user.logout);
app.get('/admin',  routes.article.admin);
app.get('/post',  routes.article.post);
app.post('/post', routes.article.postArticle);
app.get('/articles/:slug', routes.article.show);

// REST API routes
app.get('/api/articles', routes.article.list);
app.post('/api/articles', routes.article.add);
app.put('/api/articles/:id', routes.article.edit);
app.delete('/api/articles/:id', routes.article.del);



app.all('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(404);
})
// catch 404 and forward to error handler


// error handlers

// development error handler
// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(errorHandler());
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user


//module.exports = router;
module.exports = app;
```

Here is my index.js

```
exports.article = require('./article');
exports.user = require('./user');

/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.index = function(req, res, next){
    console.log(".." + res.collections);
  req.collections.articles.find({published: true}, {sort: {_id:-1}}).toArray(function(error, articles){
    if (error) return next(error);
    res.render('index', { articles: articles});
  })
};
```

If some one needs to take a look at the code base of book, please check this github url - `https://github.com/azat-co/practicalnode/tree/master/ch5/blog-express`

Comment: It should work I think.  To diagnose, perhaps try moving the `req.use(...)` that sets `req.collections` down just before defining `app.get('/', ...')` ?     And in that method, verify that `collections` is defined before assigning it to `req.collection`?

Comment: If this is a starting project with little important there, can you commit it to GitHub public rep, and I can try cloning to see if I can find the issue?  Can delete repo later.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `app.use('/', routes.index)` to `app.get('/',routes.index)`

If that doesn't work, try setting the middleware inline...

```
var setCollections  = function (req, res,next) {
  if (!collections.articles || ! collections.users) return next(new Error("No collections."))
  req.collections = collections;
  return next();
}

app.get('/', setCollections, routes.index)
```

Comment: None of the solution worked. The second solution hangs the code for a long time, and then after a while I get this error. FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
Abort trap: 6